# Отключение vhd из PowerShell по условию.

Tags: hyper-v, powershell, виртуализация

Доброго времени суток.

Есть гипервизор с пачкой виртуальных машин. VHD хранятся децентрализованно, некоторые зашифрованы. В случае принудительного ребута машины к которым подключены зашифрованные диски — отваливаются.

Можно ли одним скриптом оформить проверку типа: если VHD недоступен → отключить от машины?
И если да, то можно ли как-то одним запросом собрать местонахождения VHD для проверки, чтобы не делать такую проверку на каждый диск вручную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одним, как оказалось, нельзя. Идеальный вариант при зашифрованных дисках: проверка файла на наличие с отключением его от машины в случае его отсутствия. Ибо обычные тесты вернут true, даже если виртуальная машина остановлена.

Для каждой машины имеем такой скрипт:

```
if (-NOT (test-path путь:\до\файла.vhdx)) {Remove-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName *ИмяМашины* -ControllerType *ТипКонтроллера* -ControllerNumber *Номер* -ControllerLocation *Номер*}
```

Потом скрипты можно будет собрать в одном батнике и отправить в автозагрузку.
Если у кого-то есть более элегантный метод, прошу комментариев.